# Access to pc file using DDNS with client server application

Tags: ms-access, networking, client-server

I have an acess client server application. In the client application I set the source

> \\server\myFolderToApplication

Well know I d'like to acces to my application with distant pc using DDns
Like this

> myddns.ddns.xx\server\myFolderToApplication

Wheel I tried lot of thing but really nothing goes ok. if there is NAT configuration or something I dont know

Need your help please.

thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. Access works with an SMB file share (~Windows Server) which you cannot connect to as you try.

If you have a really fast WAN (100 Mb/s) you can connect via VPN to the remote server, but that's another story. You should discuss your requirements with your network people.